# php PDO fetchAll() - while not working, foreach works

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, while-loop, fetchall

I would like to know if i'm doing fine OR fetchAll() doesn't work with WHILE.

here is an exemple

```
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=" .$dbhost. "; dbname=" . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$page=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM page");
$page->execute();

foreach ($page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

//echo a row
//is working
}
```

however, i if try looping with a while

```
while ($row=$page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

//echo a row
//Show empty
}
```

i tryed to use only fetch(), it was working, my question: why fetchAll() doesn't work with "WHILE" ?

Comment: you probably should be using fetch instead of fetchAll in the while example.  in the for you should be fetching all before the loop condition. fetchAll returns all of your matching rows as an array or row arrays.

Comment: Yeah, fetch() is working as i said but i have a big DB, i think the best way is fetchAll()

Answer (score 21):

Fetch all returns all of the records remaining in the result set. With this in mind your foreach is able to iterate over the result set as expected.

For the equivalent while implementation should use `$page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

```
while ($row = $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   // do something awesome with row
}
```

if you want to use a while and fetch all you can do

```
$rows = $page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// use array_shift to free up the memory associated with the record as we deal with it
while($row = array_shift($rows)){
   // do something awesome with row
}
```

A word of warning though: fetch all will do exactly that, if the result size is large it will stress the resources on your machine. I would only do this if I know that the result set will be small, or I'm forcing that by applying a limit to the query.

Comment: For the people who are already used to coding while loop or their codes are already using while loop and they want to upgrade their MySQL Class into PDO, I would suggest this solution because you don't need to change your style of coding.

Comment: Yes `array_shift()` is fine to use `while()` and `fetchAll()` together. But really why? What's wrong with `foreach()` and `fetchAll()`? What's the benefit of `while()` than `foreach()` in this case?

Comment: @stack the only real benefit is that with the array_shift you can potentially free resources back to the server sooner

Comment: I always like to know this kind of small and clever points. Really thanks. +1 *(btw I'm who was worried about one `if-statement` in the PHP room `;-)`, )*

Answer (score 8):

From the PHP Manual:

> *The meaning of a while statement is simple. It tells PHP to execute the nested statement(s) repeatedly, as long as the while expression evaluates to TRUE.*

Since [the method you're using](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array, 
`while ($row=$page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` is going to set $row to an array of the entire result set. What you're expecting is for the fetchAll method to extend the [Iterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), which it does not.

A `foreach` is the right way to go here.

Answer (score 6):

no need to loop through the recordset, because `fetchAll` - well - fetches **all** the records in one command. Nice, isn't it?

```
$rows = $page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// $rows is an array containing all records...
foreach ($rows as $row)
    echo $row->fieldname;
```

Comment: Thanks @michi one problem though, its working on my local server but when i upload it to hosting it doesn't work :(

Comment: wrote this more than 4 years ago ;-) Different settings on your local machine vs your server, use google to find out how to resolve this methodically

Comment: Found the issue, I capitalized table name in SQL renaming in small letter works :p

Comment: Awesome! Simple and effective solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your case. Look here:

### script.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = "user";
$password = '';
$db_name = 'test';
$port = 3306;

try
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db_name", $user, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$page=$connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Document");
$page->execute();

while ($row = $page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

### Database test

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Document`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Document` (
  `DataID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DataID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Document`
--

LOCK TABLES `Document` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Document` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Document` VALUES (1,'!!!'),(2,'This is document 2'),(3,'This is document 3'),(4,'This is document 4'),(5,'Hello');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Document` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

### output

```
$php script.php
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["DataID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(3) "!!!"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["DataID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(18) "This is document 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["DataID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(18) "This is document 3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["DataID"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(18) "This is document 4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["DataID"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(5) "Hello"
  }
}
```

The output means, that while statement was executed once and prints all the rows, that the query should return, which is absolutely correct, because fetchAll returns an array of arrays with all the rows. PHP interprets it as true and while runs once.

While `foreach` will iterate over the array of arrays and you will have the corresponding row every time.

Answer (score 0):

With `fetchAll` In while loop you have fetched all records in the first iteration and there is nothing to fetch the next time. In `foreach` also you have fetched all records in the first line, but `foreach` uses the result for iteration.

Comment: so the only solution in this case is using foreach() ?

Comment: @Maftisi I posted a solution that uses while on a result set acquired via fetchAll.

Comment: @Mafitsi you can use `fetchAll` with `foreach` or result of `fetchAll` with `while` loop as in Orangepill's solution. While needs to evaluate the condition on every iteration.