# Using a variable in a select query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**The Problem**
I am trying to create a website, where users can post posts and then their friends can see these posts. Similar to facebook, twitter etc.
I got to the point where users can be friends and they can post things. However, I am stuck restricting the shown posts to just the user's friends' posts. At the moment every user can see every post.
I am using PDO in a MVC architecture.

**The database structure**

```
TABLE `friends` (
    `friendship_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`friendship_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_one) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_two) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

In the table above, depending on who sent the friend request to who, 'user_one' can be either myself or my friend or 'user_two' can be myself or my friend.

```
TABLE `posts` (
 `post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_text` text NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**The Model**

```
    /**
     * Get all posts from the suer's friends
     * @return array an array with several objects (the posts)
     */
    public static function getAllPosts()
    {   
        $my_id = Session::get('user_id');

        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        // get all of the user's friends
        $friendsQuery = $database->prepare("
                                    SELECT user_one FROM friends WHERE user_two = '$my_id';
                                    SELECT user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one = '$my_id';
                                    ");

        $friendsQuery->execute();
        $friends = $friendsQuery->fetchAll();
        $friendsQuery->closeCursor();

        $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$my_id' OR user_id = '$friends'");
        $query->execute(array());

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

In the above code my problem lies in the $friends variable. If I replace it manually with the user_id of my friend it works as intended.
E.g.:

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$my_id' OR user_id = '1'";
```

**The Controller**

```
    /**
     * Gets all posts (of the user and his friends).
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->View->render('post/index', array(
            'posts' => PostModel::getAllPosts()
        ));
    }
```

**The View**

```
       <?php if ($this->posts) { ?>
            <?php foreach($this->posts as $key => $value) { ?>
                <p><?= htmlentities($value->post_text); ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

**Summary**
I am not able to create a sql query, which just selects posts, which were posted by myself or my friends and does not select any other posts.

I would be very thankful, if somebody could help me out with this!

**UPDATE**
My model now looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Get all posts from the suer's friends
     * @return array an array with several objects (the posts)
     */
    public static function getAllPosts()
    {   
        $my_id = Session::get('user_id');

        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        // get all of the user's friends
        $friendsQuery = $database->prepare("
                                    SELECT user_one FROM friends WHERE user_two = '$my_id';
                                    SELECT user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one = '$my_id';
                                    ");

        $friendsQuery->execute();
        $friends = $friendsQuery->fetchAll();
        print_r($friends);
        $friendsQuery->closeCursor();

        foreach($friends as $friend)
        {
            $friend_ids[$friend->key] = $friend->val;
        }
        print_r($friend_ids);
        $friendsSQL = implode(',',$friend_ids);

        $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$my_id' OR user_id IN('$friendsSQL')");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

This is my output:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_one] => 1 ) )
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$key
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$val
>
> Array ( [] => )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all friends_id into an array and then use this code.

```
//$friends is an array.
$friendsSQL = implode(',',$friends);
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$my_id' OR user_id IN($friendsSQL)");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I do this, I can just see my own posts.

Comment: Did you add `IN` operator into your SQL and what is $friendsSQL value?

Comment: firstly, you add all friend_id values into an array and use this array in implode
function.

Comment: I understand. But is that not exactly what I am doing (I added comments to the lines of code, where I think I am doing this)?

Comment: your $friends array contains result objects. So you define a new array and
put all user_id values into this new array. It must contains id values instead of objects

Comment: I have no idea how to do that! But thank you very much for all your help! Now I know exactly what to research.

Comment: After all your amazing help,  I am almost there!! I updated my question once again and I would be beyond thankful, if you could help me over this last hurdle.

Comment: `$friend_ids = array();
foreach($friends as $friend)
        {
            $friend_ids[] = $friend->user_id;
        }`

Comment: Thank you so so much! Now, I am getting this error message: Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id. But I will figure it out somehow! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should note that `$friendsQuery->fetchAll()` will return an Array. Also, if `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is supplied as an additional argument [`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`], it would be an associative array.

The structure of the array *could* look like this :

```
Array ( [int] datasetNumber =>
    Array (
       [string] "friendship_id" => [int] 1,
       [string] "user_one"      => [int] 1,
       [string] "user_two"      => [int] 1       
    )
)
```

I gave some more Information about returning data from PDO Statements in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747622/multidimensional-array-foreach/27747751) post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not sure how this answers my question, though. I can display the posts just fine. The problem is that all posts are displayed and not just mine and the ones of my friends.

Comment: You put an array in a string; that can't work. The solution would be to "convert" the array into a string using a comma as separators, like faltay pointed out in their answer.

Answer (score -1):

your $friends variable is being returned by a fetchAll() function so will probably be a list of results. Your then using that list as a string in the query which won't work. You need to extract the ID of the friend from the $friends list.

if you're using PDO then use the variable handling built into PDO ie:

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = :variable_ID OR user_id = '1'");
$query->bindValue( ':variable_ID', $my_id, PDO::PARAM_STR ] );
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `OR user_id = '1'` at the end of your query?