# PHP: PDO fetch() returns nothing from database

Tags: php, pdo

When I use the following code, it returns nothing - no errors, no values. When I want to select just one specific row and display that data, using fetch() works fine. But the moment I put it in a loop to get multiple rows, nothing happens. Here is the code I am using:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM company WHERE position = :position AND branch = :branch ORDER BY name ASC");
$position = 23;
$branch = "Management";
$stmt->bindParam(':position', $position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':branch', $branch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(); 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Your binds name looks incorrect.

Comment: GROUP is a keyword. You might try it like this: `group` = :group

Comment: What are the values of $rank and $branch

Comment: Sorry, I changed them before I posted. The code has been modified accordingly and still shows nothing.

Comment: If you use reserved words as field names you have to put backticks around them. `AND group` is a problem. Either change the name in the table, or put backticks around group.

Comment: @developerwjk group isn't actually the name of the field, I just used it as a placeholder for my question. The field name I used in my actual table is not a reserved word.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Edited OP with the real code.

Comment: Thank you. I have reopened the question.

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it returns any errors.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php you may need to use `fetchAll()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- still no errors.

Comment: try using `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`.  That way your variables will be referenced immediately and not at `execute()`

Comment: @MichaelDoye nope, didn't work. I just want to know why I can grab/display data from a single row but when I want to do it to multiple rows using a while loop, it doesn't work.

Comment: ok one more - change your `while` to a `foreach` see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729301/php-pdo-fetchall-while-not-working-foreach-works  this is only other reason i can think of